# Why does $E_q[\log p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{z},\beta)]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{V}\phi_{ni}w_n^j\log \beta_{ij}$ hold in LDA?

Tags: machine-learning, papers, topic-model, latent-dirichlet-allocation

I'm having trouble understanding an equality that comes up in the original [LDA paper](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) by Blei et al.:

Consider the classical LDA model, i.e. for every document $\textbf{w}=(w_1,\ldots,w_N)$ in a text corpus $\mathcal{D}=\{w_1,\ldots,w_M\}$ assume that the document is created as follows$^{\dagger}$:

1. Choose $N\sim \text{Poisson}(\xi)$.
2. Choose $\theta\sim\text{Dir}(\alpha)$.
3. For each of the $N$ words $w_n$:

   (a) Choose a topic $z_n\sim \text{Multinomial}(\theta)$.
   (b) Choose a word $w_n$ from $p(w_n|z_n,\beta)$, a multinomial probability conditioned on the topic $z_n$.

In order to do inference for LDA, the authors use a variational approach with the following graphical model where $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are Dirichlet and multinomial parameters, respectively:

[image]

Let us write $p$ for the original LDA distribution and $q$ for the variational one. The equality I don't understand is given in the appendix$^{*}$ of the paper and states that:

$$E_q[\log p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{z},\beta)]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{V}\phi_{ni}w_n^j\log \beta_{ij}.$$

**My work so far:**

We can write the RHS as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{V}\phi_{ni}w_n^j\log \beta_{ij}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{V}q(z_n=i)\cdot w_n^j\cdot \log p(w_n^j=1|z_n=i)$$

and the LHS via exchangeability and de Finetti's theorem as

$$p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{z},\beta)]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}E_q[\log p(w_n|z_n,\beta)].$$

I now want to obtain the double sum from the right-hand side on the LHS as well. This looks like some sort of expected value with respect to $q$, of a discrete random variable that only depends on the values of $z_n$, conditional on $w_n$ (seemingly, as if $w_n$ was fixed) but the R.V. that we do have on the left-hand side is $\log p(w_n|z_n,\beta)$ which depends on both the values of $z_n$ and $w_n$, both not fixed. How do I continue?

---

$^{\dagger}$ Also assume that both $M$, the number of documents, and $k$, the dimensionality of the Dirichlet, are known and fixed. Furthermore, let $V$ denote the number of possible words (the "size of the vocabulary") and write every word as a $\{0,1\}^V$ vector with zeros everywhere except for the index of the word in the vocabulary list. Finally, let $\beta$ be a $k\times V$ matrix with $\beta_{ij}=p(w^j=1|z^i=1)$ and assume that both words and documents are exchangeable.

$^*$ Eq. 15, A.3